# c# xaml - Data grid doesn't show the columns I set

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I need a data grid with 3 text columns. 
This is my code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding x}">
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding x}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding x}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account" Binding="{Binding x}"/>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

But this is my result: 
[A data grid without columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwivJ.jpg)
but I have set them! 
Any ideas of what is happening?

P.S.: PLEASE DON'T FORGET TO OPEN THE LINK TO THE IMAGE! It's a screen shot of the result so everyone can understand

Comment: The ItemsSource must be bound with a Collection instance, for example CollectionViewSource.

Comment: I know, the content isn't set yet, the problem is with the element. Please, open the link "A data grid without columns". That's the pic of my problem.

Comment: You need to edit the DataGridView directly. Right Click on the DGV in Design View and select "Edit Columns".

Comment: Thank you! i'm new to this, always forgetting some small details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding x}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding x}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding x}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account" Binding="{Binding x}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `<DataGrid.Columns>` element in your XAML.

You should add the columns to the `Columns` property of the `DataGrid`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding x}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding x}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding x}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account" Binding="{Binding x}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

If you omit the `<DataGrid.Columns>` element, you are adding the columns to the `Items` Collection which is why you see no columns.

Comment: You have just duplicated my answer!

Comment: Did you somehow missed the actual explanation to why there are no columns shown? Maybe you should read my answer again then.

Comment: I did not miss the one line you added at the bottom.

Comment: It seems that the problem originated because the OP didn't "Edit Columns" on the DGV.